# How can I add grid lines to a catplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

How can I add grid lines (vertically and horizontally) to a `seaborn` catplot? I found a possibility to do that on a boxplot, but I have multiple facets and therefore need a catplot instead. And in contrast to this other answer, catplot does not allow an `ax` argument.

This code is borrowed from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
plt.show()
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT: The provided answer is working, but for faceted plots, only the last plot inherits the grid.

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Can someone explain to me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can set the grid over seaborn plots in two ways:

### 1. `plt.grid()` method:

You need to use the `grid` method inside `matplotlib.pyplot`. You can do that like so:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
plt.grid()  #just add this
plt.show()
```

Which results in this graph:
[image]

### 2. `sns.set_style()` method

You can also use `sns.set_style` which will enable grid over all subplots in any given `FacetGrid`. You can do that like so:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sns.set(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)
plt.show()
```

Which returns this graph:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain to me why this is faiilng for faceted plots? See updated question.

Comment: I edited my answer, see the second method. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: @Johannes The first solution to this question will give you vertical grid lines on your faceted plots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029406/how-to-add-vertical-gridlines-in-seaborn-catplot-with-multiple-column-plots

Answer (score 18):

Came into this question looking for a way of adding grids to a FacetGrid plot, without using the "whitegrid" style. After trying many solutions, I found that in faceted plots one has to add {'axes.grid' : True} to the set_style function:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("ticks",{'axes.grid' : True})
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="column_variable",col_wrap=4, height=2.3)
```

Comment: This worked great, and is even simpler as it directly uses a seaborn function.  
It is working for me in with `relplot`

Comment: This is very easy, but similar to @Anwarvic sns.set_style() method above, it only gives horizontal grid lines.

Comment: I found this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029406/how-to-add-vertical-gridlines-in-seaborn-catplot-with-multiple-column-plots

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct way to add grids for all axes:

```
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", col="diet", data=exercise)

for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.grid()
```