# How to add vertical gridlines in seaborn catplot with multiple column plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a catplot using the following code.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
sns.set_style({'axes.grid': True})
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
```

But this does not plot vertical gridlines. How can I add them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like seaborn actively turns off vertical grid lines ([see here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/c9af2977478e524cedd69aaea020dea46f46c6fc/seaborn/categorical.py#L372)).

You have to re-enable them on each axes created by `catplot`:

```
sns.set_style("ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.grid(True, axis='both')
```

[image]

Comment: This method is great! I've shared a link to this solution on a couple of other questions, since it answers them better than other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply use：

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
```

It works with other sns plotting functions as well.